# how to use run section to execute file and read the params from function

Tags: inno-setup

how to use Run section to execute a file but read the params from a function XYZ:

```
[Run]
Filename: {app}\e.exe; Parameters: funcXYZ('1'); Description: {cm:ALaunchProgram,{#ti}};
```

I dont want to use ShellExec or Exec.

Comment: Maybe you could try: `Parameters: "{code:FunctionName}" ;`

Comment: sounds very good, but I get invalid prototype message?

Comment: Maybe you could post that function? Probably TLama or Deanna will be able to solve it for you :) Becasue maybe it has wrong prototype. 
What about s.thing like that 
`function FunctionName(Default: String): String;`

Comment: @Tom to use the {code: snippet, you have to call a parameterless function.

Comment: @jachguate: actually you can't call a parameterless function. :)

Comment: @Miral, you're right, my bad! :(. +1 for your answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See the help file](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptconstants.htm).

The function you are calling must have **exactly** the signature shown in the help -- in particular note that it must accept a single String parameter, even if you don't actually pass anything to it.